# Is there way to get computed metrics of pseudo elements in Safari web inspector?

Tags: html, css, safari, pseudo-element, web-inspector

I am primarily using Chrome developer tools for debugging html/css/js, but now I needed to debug different rendering of pseudo element in Chrome vs Safari.

I could not find a way to get computed metrics (or any computed css properties) of :before pseudo element in Safari.

Pictures for better explanation:

Chrome:
[image: :before pseudo element is shown as element in Chrome's inspector]
Safari:
[image: No pseudo element and I can't see option to show them]

Am I missing something? Option, switch..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to changelog, this issue has been addressed in Safari 9.1.

> HTML pseudo-elements are now visible in the DOM tree allowing for easier styling. The ::before element is highlighted in Figure 1.

[image: Safari 9.1 web inspector screenshot]

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_1.html

Answer (score 1):

You're not able to view the pseudo tag directly within the DOM inspection window but you can view the pseudo styles within the style inspector window in the right column.

Here is an example from one of my applications. Sorry for not embedding the image directly within the answer; I apparently need 10 rep points to post images:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kf6i85d9kvarxzs/safari_screenshot.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Thank you but this does not answer my question: how to get computed metrics of that element. For example, if I use "width: inherit" or "left: 10%", I would like to see what are exact computed metrics (to be sure the pseudo element inherits property from element i want, or if it is relatively positioned as I want).